# cancel href using jquery not working

Tags: jquery, href

I'm trying to remove the links to determinated class of  so the Javascript it's executed instead ( onclick and things like that ) (and if of corse, javascript it's enabled. that's why i want to keep the href in the source code.. any way, i'm trying with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
                   $('.remove').attr('href', '#');
        });

</script>
```

but it doesn't :S

Comment: does the anchor have an initial value?

Comment: `$('.remove').attr('href', '#');` will replace the value of `href` to #, resulting `href="#"` in a link. Are expecting it to remove the href?

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead...

```
$('.remove').removeAttr('href');
```

Setting the `href` to a blank fragment `#` is bad practice, hacky and ugly. It often makes the browser jump to the top of the page.

Alternatively, with your click handlers you could do...

```
$('a').click(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
});
```

You can also `return false`.

Comment: so if i post this as is, will the function under onclick="" will be exectuted? that's what i'm trying. Remove the href so the onclick is executed instead

Comment: @Toni Michel Caubet Yes, it should. But without seeing all of your code, I need to make some assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

I kind of understand what your trying to do and the right way to go about it is not removing the # href , i would not advise on returning false because you wont be able to pass the jQuery object:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#anchorId").click(function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     //do stuff
   });
});
```

Comment: I agree with using event.preventDefault() but can you explain what you mean by return false not passing the jQuery object?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the recommended **event.preventDefault()** as the last line for your event handler.
You don't event need to change the href value.

Base on your code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
               $('.remove').click(function(event) {
                       // your Javascript stuff

                       // Most import jquery line
                       event.preventDefault();
               }
    });
```

Comment: so if i post this as is, will the function under onclick="" will be exectuted? that's what i'm trying. Remove the href so the onclick is executed instead

Comment: `event.preventDefault();` doesn't need to be the last line, in fact, I usually make it the first line, so it is clear the default behaviour isn't invoked.

Answer (score -1):

To make it more easy, just using an HTML:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" onclick="return false;">Stack Over Flow</a>
```

If you want to do a JS, with function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function RemoveHREF(type){
  $(type).attr('href', '#');
 }
</script>
```

Your HTML should be

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" class="URL5">Stack Over Flow</a>
```

Now to call for the function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  RemoveHREF('.URL5');
 });
</script>
```